# No se me despliega el menu

Tags: laravel

tengo el siguiente codigo html en mi proyecto de laravel para generar una vista con mi menu de opciones desplegables, cada opcion esta relacionada con un evento de click a una variable de nombre "menu",sin embargo las opciones no se despliegan al momento de seleccionarlos

No se que no estoy viendo, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Agradecido con cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme

este es el codigo:

```
 <div class="sidebar">
            <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li @click="menu=0" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="icon-speedometer"></i> Escritorio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-title">
                        Mantenimiento
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-bag"></i> Almacén</a>
                        <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
                            <li @click="menu=1" class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-bag"></i> Categorías</a>
                            </li>
                            <li @click="menu=2" class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-bag"></i> Artículos</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-wallet"></i> Compras</a>
                        <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
                            <li @click="menu=3" class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-wallet"></i> Ingresos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li @click="menu=4" class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-notebook"></i> Proveedores</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-basket"></i> Ventas</a>
                        <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
                            <li @click="menu=5" class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-basket-loaded"></i> Ventas</a>
                            </li>
                            <li @click="menu=6" class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-notebook"></i> Clientes</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-people"></i> Acceso</a>
                        <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
                            <li @click="menu=7" class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="i#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Usuarios</a>
                            </li>
                            <li @click="menu=8" class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-user-following"></i> Roles</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-pie-chart"></i> Reportes</a>
                        <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
                            <li @click="menu=9" class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-chart"></i> Reporte Ingresos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li  @click="menu=10" class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-chart"></i> Reporte Ventas</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li @click="menu=11" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-book-open"></i> Ayuda <span class="badge badge-danger">PDF</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li @click="menu=12" class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="icon-info"></i> Acerca de...<span class="badge badge-info">IT</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <button class="sidebar-minimizer brand-minimizer" type="button"></button>
        </div>
```

esta es un  vista del menu de la parte izquierda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `@click` es una directiva de laravel blade?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ al menos nunca la he visto

Comment: es de vue indica que cuando se haga clic en esa parte se cambie el valor de la variable al valor asignado, esa parte si funciona, lo que no funciona es el despliegue del menu

Comment: No creo que haya algo para hacer con laravel. mejor etiqueta la pregunta con `html`, y si usas [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) podría ir `jquery`, o `vue` si ya lo estás usando.